# Doxygen - Generic Block for Duplication

Tags: doxygen

Is there any way in `doxygen` (version 1.8.14) to create a generic text block that can be repeated in *code documentation/markdown pages/etc.*?

I don't mean copying certain types of text using `@copydoc`... this only works for "a member (of a class, file or group), a class, a namespace, a group, a page, or a file" (as per the [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#copydoc)). I have many small snippets of text that I would like replicated without having to directly copy/paste or create a page for (I would have hundreds of "related pages" if they each had to be their own page).

Any help is appreciated!

Editing for example:
I have requirement text that I would like to duplicate and cross-reference in tables and code.

I currently have:

Definition (Markdown; I would like the definitions in a single file if possible like the below; `@snippet` appears to only work with a distinct file per text block):

```
@section req_1 Requirement 1
My text.

@section req_2 Requirement 2
My other text.
```

Code Cross-ref (C header):

```
@details Linked requirement(s): @link req_1 Requirement 1. @endlink
void functionForReq1(void);
```

Table Cross-ref (markdown); **here, I would like to paste the requirement text in directly instead of duplicating it with copy/paste** (the "My text." portion):

```
| Requirement ID           | Text     | Cross-Reference     |
| -----------------------: | :------- | :------------------ |
| @link req_1 [1] @endlink | My text. | ::functionForReq1() |
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right, when not please provide more information and some example, but did you have at \snippetdoc and \includedoc?

Comment: This is close, but I don't really want a unique file for each of my "snippets" (I would have hundreds of files with 1-2 lines in them each).

Comment: I think you can achieve this with \snippetdoc <filename> (block-id) as in the file <filename> you can have multiple snippets. There can be multiple snippets, with of course different bloc-ids,  in one file.

Comment: I am not sure one can indicate a block-id in a markdown file... I haven't had success? I think I would have to make them *.dox at the very least?

Comment: Multiple snippets in md file is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using a snippet file with multiple snippets and the command \snippetdoc should do the trick.

The main file (aa.md):

```
Some md?
========

Some initial text

\snippetdoc snippets.md snip1

\n
Some more text

\snippetdoc snippets.md snip2
```

The file with the snippets (example/snippets.md):

```
[snip1]
First snippet
<table>
<tr><th> Requirement ID           </th><th> Text     </th><th> Cross-Reference     </th></tr>
<tr><td> @link req_1 [1] @endlink </td><td> My text. </td><td> ::functionForReq1() </td><tr>
</table>
[snip1]

[snip2]
Second snippet
[snip2]
```

Change in Doxyfile:

```
EXAMPLE_PATH           = example
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = aa.md
```

Comment: Strange, that works except in a table. My initial guess is that there is a newline being inserted somewhere in the \snippetdoc "pasting"? I tried like this without luck either: [snip1]First snippet[snip1]

Comment: I see the problem in case of, markdown, tables. When using HTML tables it looks OK to me, see edited answer.

Comment: I've edited the question for further clarity. I mean inserting the snippet into another table, not the snippet being a table :) But, I'm thinking the approach of an explicit HTML table may be the only way...